# search engine using pdo error

Tags: php, html

Im working on a simple search engine, what I have is working fine but I want to change this line of code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$search."%') or (`type` LIKE '%".$search."%')";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE (`name` LIKE '%:search%') or (`type` LIKE '%:search%')";
```

but for some reason this is not working

here is the full php code

```
<?php
require("../login/connect.php");
$search = $_GET['query']; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$search."%') or (`type` LIKE '%".$search."%')";


$query_params = array(':search' => $_GET['query']);

try
{
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
  die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$min_length = 3;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
{
  echo "<table border='0' width='600' align='center' cellpadding='1'>"; 
  echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#03acfa' >
          <td height='35px' width='200px'><b>Mobile Name</b></td>
          <td><b>Mobile Type</b></td>
        </tr>";

    foreach($rows as $row):
    { 
      echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#93dafb'>
              <td height='25px'>". $row['name'] ."</td> <td>".$row['type']."</td>
            </tr>" ;
    }
    endforeach; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$query_params = array(':search' => $_GET['query']);
```

to

```
$query_params = array(':search' => "%".$search."%");
```

and now you can use this on the query

```
(`name` LIKE :search) or (`type` LIKE :search)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Bindings can't be partial like that. You'll have to use `LIKE :search` in the query, and then inside the variable you are binding include the `%`s

Comment: You are saying that the query needs to look like "SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE (`name` LIKE :search ) or (`type` LIKE :search )";